# Swift 2.0 SKPhysicsBody nil check

Tags: swift, null, skphysicsbody, swift2

After updating to Swift 2.0 this no longer works:

```
if contact.bodyA != nil && contact.bodyB != nil {
```

Comes back with:

```
Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two Bool operands
```

I tried a nil check separately for each body with nested if statements and it seems that you can no longer nil check a physics body...

Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS9, `bodyA` and `bodyB` are no longer optional:

```
class SKPhysicsContact : NSObject {
    var bodyA: SKPhysicsBody { get }
    var bodyB: SKPhysicsBody { get }

    // ...
}
```

Therefore you can't check whether they're `nil`. To solve your problem, just use `bodyA` and `bodyB` as you would any other non-optional.

Comment: I put these checks in place, because on multiple collisions you can get in a situation where the body has been removed during the second collision.
Also where did you find the information on that ? I've been looking all over...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean... Just check the [`SKPhysicsContact` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsContact/bodyA) you can see neither `bodyA` or `bodyB` are optional.

Comment: I agree, it would be good if they'd do that - perhaps someone else knows where to find it... The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFramework_Ref/index.html#other) is always helpful though :) Glad I could help, if that solved your problem could you mark it as correct?